# Do bivalves such as oysters feel pain or fear?

Tags: ethics, animal-welfare, philosophy, animal-suffering

In moral arguments for veganism, the pain, stress, and fear experienced by animals is often given as an argument.  I have read [some arguments](https://sentientist.org/2013/05/20/the-ethical-case-for-eating-oysters-and-mussels/) that vegetarians should be OK with eating oysters and mussels.

What evidence exists (either way) that clams, oysters, cockles, mussels, scallops feel pain, stress, and fear, or not?

Answer (score 6):

It's highly unlikely, due to them not having any brain or central nervous system. All they have is a small nerve network and two ganglia near their esophagus.

The whole nervous system is basically two nerve centers, one that controls the muscles and the other one that controls the "foot" and other sensory organs. It's unknown whether the cerebral ganglia can feel pain, or just sensations such as food in it's mouth.

[There](https://sentientist.org/2013/05/20/the-ethical-case-for-eating-oysters-and-mussels/) [are](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/marc-bekoff/vegans-shouldnt-eat-oyste_b_605786.html) [many](http://bitesizevegan.com/ethics-and-morality/are-oysters-vegan-gary-yourofsky-the-vegan-black-metal-chef/) [articles](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/do-oysters-feel-pain) [about](http://www.peta2.com/blog/oyster-mussel-clam-scallop-facts/) whether oysters and such are vegan and do they feel pain, but the overall consenus is: They likely don't feel pain, but whether you eat them depends on your definition of vegan. Do you abstain from eating animals altogether or just animals that feel pain...

Comment: I agree they likely don't feel pain but I think it's misleading to suggest that any consensus among vegans would be that oysters are 'safe'.  Any conclusion by someone who isn't vegan should be taken with a massive pinch of salt if they are claiming to specify what is or isn't acceptable on a vegan diet.

Comment: Oysters are not vegan. Veganism is not a rationale that motivates people to abstain from consuming animal product, its the act of abstaining from consuming animal product. A vegan will not consume oysters (or wear pearls) regardless of whether or not they believe that oysters feel pain or fear.

Comment: @Nephenine that may be your opinion, but that's not necessarily all vegan's opinions. I'll edit though.

Comment: [http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vegan?s=t]

Comment: @Nephenine also, every time you past that link it's broken. the ] at the end becomes part of the URL.

Comment: @user177 the question asks about vegetarians - and an this would include ovo-vegetarians which do eat animal tissue that was never sentient.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to eggs.   it is true that they are not or ever were sentient.    However, the hens that laid them usually have a pretty awful life.   All male chicks are destroyed - often in a very cruel way.
Molluscs are a different problem. They do seem to react to what would be painful stimuli in vertebrates but whether they are in any way 'conscious' is open to doubt by most scientists

Comment: The question was about molluscs, not eggs/chicken.  NB, Germany recently banned destroying male chicks.